# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages - Complex model property is null after returning Page()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm apparently not understanding something fundamental about model binding complex properties in Razor Pages. When my model isn't valid, I `return Page();` but I get an exception when referencing a complex property of the model. Here's a slim version of what I have:

Models:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Director Director { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Director
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
public Movie Movie { get; set; }

[BindProperty, Required]
public string Description { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    // Pretend we're loading from the DB...
    Movie = new Movie
    {
        Id = 1,
        Title = "Citizen Kane",
        Director = new Director
        {
            Id = 101,
            Name = "Orson Wells"
        }
    };

    return Page();
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Page();

    Movie.Description = Description;

    //Save to DB
    // ...

    return RedirectToPage("/Index");
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<h5>@Model.Movie.Title</h5>
<h6>Directed by @Model.Movie.Director.Name</h6>

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Movie.Id" />
    <textarea asp-for="Description" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I leave Description blank, the model is invalid in `OnPost` and returns `Page()` as expected. But then I get a `System.NullReferenceException; Object reference not set to an instance of an object` here:

```
<h6>Directed by @Model.Movie.Director.Name</h6>
```

Why is `Movie.Director` null here? Do I have to get the data again when returning `Page()`? I was thinking it would fire `OnGet()` again but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `OnGet()` would be supposed to be fired. I wonder its not working reason as well +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is `Movie.Director` null here? Do I have to get the data again when returning `Page()`? I was thinking it would fire `OnGet()` again but it doesn't.

No, the `OnGet` method is not called automatically when your `OnPost` method is actually executing. Both handlers are independent from each other and the only thing they share is the underlying Razor view and the page model. If your view requires data to be loaded into your model, then you will need to do that for the `OnPost` as well.

You *could* call the GET method from within your POST method, but depending on what you actually do in your `OnGet`, this might overwrite data that has been set explicitly by the `OnPost`. What I would recommend instead is to add an additional method that will be called by both `OnGet` and `OnPost` to set up *shared* model properties that your view needs to render.

```cs
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    Movie = LoadMovie();
    return Page();
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Movie = LoadMovie();
        return Page();
    }

    // …
    return RedirectToPage("/Index");
}

private Movie LoadMovie()
{
    // …
}
```

Note that you will also only need to execute this method if you actually need to render your page view.

---

The confusion maybe stems from what the `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods are for: With Razor pages, these methods are the *entry point*. They are called by the ASP.NET Core framework when a route is being requested that matches the Razor page. If it’s a GET request, the `OnGet` method is being called; if it’s a POST request, it’s the `OnPost` method. There is no direct relationship between these methods other that they share the same view (the cshtml) and the model.

Since these methods are the entry points, a POST request will not execute the `OnGet` method and a GET request will not execute the `OnPost` method—unless of course you make those calls yourself within these methods.

Now, when you return `Page()` then the only thing that happens is that you tell the ASP.NET Core framework to then render your Razor view with the data that you prepared in the page model. So it just renders the `cshtml` passing the page model as the view’s model. This will however not cause any calls to `OnGet` or `OnPost` at this point since those already ran to get *into* the Razor page execution.

That means that if you want to execute certain logic always before rendering the view, then you will need to execute that logic explicitly from within your page handlers, before returning `Page()`.

Comment: Why wouldn't he get a null-ref exception at the very beginning?

Comment: @snr What do you mean with beginning? Which beginning? `Movie.Title`? Since the `Movie` property has a `[BindProperty]` attribute, the property will be *created* (but not filled) by the Razor page. So `Movie` is not null, but `Movie.Title` and `Movie.Director` is; but only `Movie.Director.Name` will cause a NRE.

Comment: ‘Movie.Director.Name’ is meant. Doesn’t he run into it at the first run, that is by ‘index.cshtml’?

Comment: By “first run” do you mean the GET request? There, the `OnGet` will explicitly set the `Movie` property. It’s only when submitting the form that the POST request is being made and if the model state is invalid then, the view is being rendered without explicitly setting `Movie` again.

Comment: yes, as the uri is put into the address bar, he gets GET request. If OnGet is called, why isn’t it called when he calls Page()? How is OnGet triggered “at the very beginning” otherwise?

Comment: Returning `Page()` does not call `OnGet`. `OnGet` and `OnPost` are the entry points for the Razor page and they are called by the ASP.NET Core framework if there is a GET or POST request is being made to the route of the Razor page. Returning `Page()` within these methods just tells the framework to then *render* the Razor view of the Razor page. It does not trigger additional method calls in the Razor page model.

Comment: I couldn’t catch the point if you didn’t write that comment that you should add to your answer.

Comment: @snr I’ve expanded my answer with a summary of these details.

Comment: Thanks, poke, this really helps. So in `OnPost` if I just want to save the data and stay on the same page, should I return `Page()` instead of `RedirectToPage("/Index")`?

Comment: @DakotaPaul Assuming you want to show the validation errors that caused the invalid model state, you should return `Page()` since that will keep the submitted information and allows the user to correct their data. Otherwise, if you want to throw all that information away, you can return a redirect.